# Infopaht forms display in browser and for printing them

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

I have two questions that in sharepoint 2007 with infopath 2007, 
1)"**infopath form library forms(.xml) are not opening in browser**" though i have made the option to "open in browser".

2)Another question is how to "**retrieve the forms stored in the infopath libraries** to show in aspx pages **and to print**" it directly.

Please reply me if any one knows the answer.

Comment: Have you set the settings for your template as well as Form library to open Forms in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Within the form options, make sure that the compatibility is set to Web Browser Form. If you are publishing the form to a document library within SharePoint be sure to check that the form is going to be opened in the browser. Last, make sure that under the advanced options in your document library settings that the browser is set to "Display as a Web page".

If your form has full trust permission you will need administrator approval to complete the publish. This requires that the form is saved in a location that can be accessed by STSADM.

2) If the above steps work you will be able to view and print your form from within the browser.

Good Luck!

Comment: Do you know if you can do it when the Form type is `SharePoint List Form`? (in other words, a list customised with InfoPath)